# AccessからMYSQL(MariaDB)に接続する方法

Tags: mysql, xampp, ms-access, odbc

MySQLに対してMicrosoft Accessから接続と操作を行いたいのですがうまくいきません。
間違っている個所、抜けている個所がありましたらご指摘、ご教授をお願いいたします。

環境
PC Windows10 (64bit)
XAMPP 7.3.6 (64bit)
Access 2010 (32bit)
使用したODBCドライバ mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.16-winx64.msi

[Access から MySQLに接続する方法](http://accessmyusql.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-8.html)

上記サイトの「パススルークエリ」を参考に試したのですが、エラーで落ちてしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
ODBC--'{MySQL ODBC 8.0.16 DRIVER}localhost' への接続が失敗しました。
```

記述したODBC接続文字列は以下の通りです。

```
ODBC;Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0.16 DRIVER};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=test;UID=root;PWD=;
```

その後、両方のドライバを試してみましたが、今度はMySQL自体がエラーで
動かなくなりました。

その時のログが下記です。

```
2019-06-27  9:07:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-06-27  9:07:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-06-27  9:07:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-06-27  9:07:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-06-27  9:07:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-06-27  9:07:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-06-27  9:07:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-06-27  9:07:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-06-27  9:07:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-06-27  9:07:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-06-27  9:07:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-06-27  9:07:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-06-27  9:07:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.15 started; log sequence number 42861982; transaction id 184187
2019-06-27  9:07:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-06-27  9:07:02 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-06-27  9:07:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190627  9:07:02
2019-06-27  9:07:02 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: XAMPP側のMySQLログはどうなっていますか？記録されていますか？

Comment: 接続先が`localhost`になっていますが、MySQLとAccessは共存している環境ということでしょうか？

Comment: ODBCドライバの64/32の違いでは？ [MySQLのODBC接続は設定できたけどAccessから接続できない](http://mgate.info/db/878/)、[64bit版Windowsに32bit版のAccess入れたらODBC設定がちょっと面倒だった話](https://aimstogeek.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/12/06/191101) @cubickさん指摘のように全部が同一PC内だと何か違うのかもしれませんが。

Comment: 少し古い記事ですが、これが詳しそうです。[ODBC接続に失敗したので、試しました　－32bit版ODBCドライバが表示されないので－](https://t-inada-shokai.blogspot.com/2014/04/odbc_19.html)、[64bit版WindowsにおけるODBC設定](http://dupont-kedama.blogspot.com/2013/01/64bitwindowsodbc.html) 32/64両方インストールが良さそうですが、こんな記事もあります。[MySQL のインストールと Windows7 64ビットの ODBC と 32ビットの ODBC](https://winofsql.jp/matrix/ginpro/patio.cgi?mode=view&no=415)

Comment: ありがとうございます。今は、サイト様の通りに沿ってテストをしています。そのため、XAMPPとAccessは同一のPCです。もちろん、最終的には変更しますが、今は練習のため自分のPCで行っています。…そのうえで、32bit版のテストを試していますが、やはり結果は同じでした。[64bit版Windowsに32bit版のAccess入れたらODBC設定がちょっと面倒だった話]の通りにDOSプロンプトでデータソース画面を開けはしましたが、そもそも参考にしてもらったサイト様の方法では、データソースの設定を行わず、ODBC接続文字列だけで接続する方法だと思ったので、データソースの設定は一切行っていません。